# Extract sequences from a fasta file

Tags: text-processing

I have a fasta file (not in right format) that contains hundreds of thousands of different lengths of DNA sequences like this:

```
>NODE_213384_length_62_cov_8686_ID_2134025ATCGAATGGAATCATCGAATGGACTCGAATGGAATAATCATTGAACGGAATCGAATGG>NODE_213385_length_62_cov_7933_ID_2134027ATCATCATCGAATGGAATCGAATGGAATCATCGAATGGACTCGAATGGAATAATCATTGAAC>NODE_213386_length_62_cov_7184_ID_2134029AATGATTATTCCATTCGAGTCCATTCGATGATTCCATTCGATTCCATTCGATGATGATTGCA>NODE_213387_length_62_cov_8639_ID_2134031CAGAGCAGACTTGAAACACTCTTTTTGTGGAATTTGCAAGTGGAGATTTCAGCCGCTTTGAG>NODE_213388_length_62_cov_6833_ID_2134033AGACTTGAAACACTCTTTTTGTGGAATTTGCAAGTGGAGATTTCAGCCGCTTTGAGGTCAAT
```

I'd like to use a simple Linux command to extract those sequences longer than  1000bp and output in a right fasta format like this:

```
>NODE_213384_length_62_cov_8686_ID_2134025
ATCGAATGGAATCATCGAATGGACTCGAATGGAATAATCATTGAACGGAATCGAATGG
>NODE_213385_length_62_cov_7933_ID_2134027
ATCATCATCGAATGGAATCGAATGGAATCATCGAATGGACTCGAATGGAATAATCATTGAAC
>NODE_213386_length_62_cov_7184_ID_2134029
AATGATTATTCCATTCGAGTCCATTCGATGATTCCATTCGATTCCATTCGATGATGATTGCA
>NODE_213387_length_62_cov_8639_ID_2134031
CAGAGCAGACTTGAAACACTCTTTTTGTGGAATTTGCAAGTGGAGATTTCAGCCGCTTTGAG
```

Appreciate anyone who can help with this.

Comment: Why, in the name of all that is cretinous, did you replace the text output with an image of the same text?

Comment: Yes. I replaced the original texts with images since the text did not display the ">" in the beginning of each line.

Comment: wouldn't it have been simpler (and much, much better) to simply edit the question and add the missing `>` characters?  You've now replaced usable, copy-pastable, editable, searchable text with a useless graphic. that you can't do anything with (and will be illegible on high-resolution displays)

Comment: i've reverted the edit so it's text again and reformatted as code (using the `{}` icon in the SE editor), which preserves the `>` characters (which otherwise would be interpreted as block-quote)

Comment: Is the title for each sequence always the same number of characters? This is unix/linux, so explain what bp are. In any case, does sequence only include ATGC, or are there ambiguous nucleotides?

Comment: Sequences only contain ATCG, no ambiguous nucleotides. The title of sequence has same format but may not same number of characters. For example, one is ...._12.837_.....the other may be ......156_65992_..... BP represent base pairs which are number of letters. Thanks.

Comment: You are absolutely right and your edit is great. Forgive me. It was my first time posting a question here and I was not so familiar with everything. I understand the text would be helpful for trying-out commands but there were missing > that may confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a two step process; first split up into the target format, then print the line pairs where the DNA sequence is long enough. E.g., on the assumption that `1000bp` refers to the DNA sequence character length (rather than the value following the word "length"), it could be the following

```
cat inputfile | sed -e 's/>/\n>/g' -e 's/\(ID_[0-9]*\)/\n\1/g' |\
awk -F_ '$1=="NODE" { n=$0; next; } length($0)>1000 { print n; print ">" $0;}' \
> outputfile
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph. I am not a professional Linux person. Could you clarify more for where the input file should be? I guess you print the output on screen. Can you put the output in your command?

Comment: Sure; I added input and output files to the command. It's broken up into three lines for readability. You can type it on a single line by not typing "backslash newline".

Answer (score 0):

A "simple Linux command" might look something like:

```
sed 's/\(>[^ACGT]*_[0-9]\+\)\([ACGT]\+\)/\1\n\2\n/g' yourdnafile |egrep -B1 '^[ACGT]{1000}'
```

The sed part breaks down the into 2 lines per set, and the grep shows and match over 1000 and the line preceding it (-B1).

or this might be even more simple:

```
sed 's/\(>[^>ACGT]*\)\([ACGT]\{1000\}[ACGT]*\)/\1\n\2\n/g;s/>[^>ACGT\n]*[ACGT]\+//g' yourdnafile
```

Comment: Thanks Mel. I just tried your both commands. The first did not work. The second seemed working but no output. Since I have limited experience of Linux, could you fix it?

Comment: They are both looking for 1000 characters matching A,C,G, or T. Not being familiar with DNA, perhaps I have misunderstood what 1000bp should look like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a very long line. You might run into problems with sed and awk as they eat up available memory to handle this task (depends on your file size/line length of course). So, taking the two-stage approach, but with memory constraints, you can use `tr` followed by one of the awk, perl, or sed solutions above.

```
head -20 inputfile | 
tr '>' '\n'  > stage1
perl -ne 'print ">$1 $2\n" if /^(.*?)([ACGTU]+)$/ && length($2)>1000' < stage1 > output
```

Once you're satisfied it works with the first 20 lines, do it for real in a single pipeline:

```
tr '>' '\n' inputfile | 
perl -ne 'print ">$1 $2\n" if /^(.*?)([ACGTU]+)$/ && length($2)>1000' > output
```

My perl script might not be as efficient as others, but should get the job done. I wrote it for clarity. Print out the label followed by a space and then the associated base pairs and newline, if and only if there is such a line that contains more than 1000 base pairs.